# Dragging a file to another disk on Windows won't delete it

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, drag-and-drop

When you move a file from a specific disk let's X to another disk (let's say Y) it won't delete the  file from X unless you cut it, and I know that's the default behavior on Windows : but is it possible to change that drag-and-drop behavior so the moved file wouldn't stay on the first drive ? I have both a SSD and an HDD and when I drag a file from my HDD and drop it to my SSD, the file stay on my HDD, it is pretty annoying to always cut and paste or holding a key while dragging the file

Comment: Use the Right button (instead of the left). People who regularly Drag-n-Drop with the right button, almost forget how it even worked with the left one.

Comment: When you di this you get a context menu where you could select if you want to move the file or just copy. I would rather use shortkey control + x and then control + v

Comment: Try to hold shift when you move the file

Comment: The questioner did in fact mention both of those in the question,  Ivan Viktorovic.

Comment: @Psycogeek Thanks for your answers ! But it's strange ! When I drag-n-drop a file using the right-click : it works great on my Windows 7 computer and it's pretty cool ! But unfortunately the "right-click-drag-n-drop" doesn't work on Windows 8.1 (tested on two computers) it only brings up the context menu. Ivan Yes I knew that I could hold the shift key and as I can see : it's the easiest solution, I though that there was something else like an option to change that behavior, but anyway : holding the shift key won't make me lose a myriad of hours.